# Great Leap to the Right

Tags: code-golf

Given a string `s` consisting of characters a-z lowercase, generate 5 arrays `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, and `a5` of size `n` (length of `s`) where the `i`-th element of each array represents the index of the next occurrence of the `i`-th character in `s`, with the following conditions:

- If no such occurrence exists, set the value to `n` (0-based indexing) or `n+1` (1-based indexing) depending on the indexing convention you use.
- `a1` represents the 1st next occurrence of the character, `a2` represents the 2nd next occurrence, `a3` represents the 4th next occurrence, `a4` represents the 8th next occurrence, and `a5` represents the 16th next occurrence.

This is a code golf challenge, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Here are some test cases. They all use 0-based indexing.

**Input:** `aakakakakka`
**Output:**

```
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9 11 11
3 5 6 7 8 10 9 11 11 11 11
7 10 9 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

**Input:** `sydgdtsfixuvhdgisifdyovjcgs`
**Output:**

```
6 20 4 14 13 27 16 18 15 27 27 22 27 19 25 17 26 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
16 27 13 25 19 27 26 27 17 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
```

**Input:** `qmorzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz`
**Output:**

```
59 59 59 59 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
59 59 59 59 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 59
59 59 59 59 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 59 59 59
59 59 59 59 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59
59 59 59 59 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 59
```

Comment: Can we output the list transposed, so N lists of length 5 instead of 5 lists of length N?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 18 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
-∘≠↑¨<⊒¨⍷⊸∾⍟(2⋆↕5)
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkC3iiJjiiaDihpHCqDziipLCqOKNt+KKuOKIvuKNnygy4ouG4oaVNSkKCnRlc3RzIOKGkCDin6ggImFha2FrYWtha2thIiwgInN5ZGdkdHNmaXh1dmhkZ2lzaWZkeW92amNncyIsICJxbW9yenp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6enp6eiLin6kKCuKNieKJjeKlij7ii4jin5w+4p+cRsKodGVzdHM=)

The *Progressive Index of* `⊒` does the heavy lifting here.

`...⍟(2⋆↕5)` 1, 2, 4, 8 and 16 times:
`⍷⊸∾` prepend the unique characters to the string.

`<⊒¨` For each of the resulting strings find the progressive indices of the characters in the input string. *progressive* means that each index can only be used once. The length of the input is used as a *not found* value.
`-∘≠↑` From each resulting integer list, take as many values from the back as there are characters in the input.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>111</s> 109 bytes

*With thanks to **JvdV** for the 2-byte save*.

```
=LET(
    b,LEN(A1),
    c,SEQUENCE(b),
    d,MID(A1,c,1),
    IFERROR(FIND(0,SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,c+1,b),d,0,{1,2,4,8,16}))+c-1,b)
)
```

0-based. Input in cell `A1`. Generates an *n*-row-by-5-column array, where *n* is the length of the input string.

Comment: Good thinking! I get 109, not 108, though.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Typo =)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 35 bytes

```
(2^i.5){0|:i.@#+(#,~^:16[:I.{.=])\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBwyguU89Us9qgxipTz0FZW0NZpy7OytAs2spTr1rPNlYzRu9/anJGvkKagnpiYjYEZieqc4EF1aE0ULK4MiU9paQ4LbOitCwjJT2zODMtpTK/LCs5vRhTcWFuflEVeUD9PwA)

- `(…)\.`: Apply the verb inside to each suffix of the string, in order of start point.

  - `{.` `=` `]`: Check for equality (`=`) between the first element (`{.`) and the whole suffix (`]`, identity function). This produces a list of Booleans.
  - (`[:` to use monadically.) `I.` produces a list of indices of the 1s.
  - `#` `,` `~` `^:` `16`: Take the length of the suffix (`#`) and append (`,` with `~` to reverse operands) it to the list, repeating 16 times (`^:` `16`).
- `i.` `@` `#` `+`: Add (`+`) [0,1,2,3,…] (`#` gives the length of the string, and `i.` produces that many numbers). This adjusts the numbers from indices in the suffixes to indices in the whole string.
- `0` `|:`: Transpose.
- `(2^i.5){`: Take the rows at indices 1, 2, 4, 8, 16.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

Expects an array of characters. Returns an array of 5 arrays of integers, using 0-based indexing.

```javascript
f=(s,k=5)=>k--?[...f(s,k),s.map(g=(c,i,q)=>!s[i]|q>>k?i:g(c,[...s,c].indexOf(c,i+1),-~q))]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY@xbsMgEIZ3PwX1Yk7BSB26pMKZOvcBHAYEhmASiLnESqqqr@4Gp0/Qu@FO3/8Nd6OaFersz5c2JjMsixUUWRBvILrQtruec24LAYb8pM7UCaqZZ9Mjf8Hey@@p68LOb90DFxmZltxHM9w@bTE3r8DanwlAbnu5vPcVIbVS4dlB1awAvBtnLmj97TofjPPorbmnedQOn8J0Svnrf1VXsuI25Q@lDxSJ6IhOEdNx4MfkqKXr0RLW53KJMx@Tj7QhDcDfuo8NkA1ZJyy/)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (               // f is a recursive function taking:
  s,                //   s[] = input string, as an array of characters
  k = 5             //   k = counter, initialized to 5
) =>                //
k-- ?               // decrement k; if it was not 0: 
  [ ...f(s, k),     //   append the result of a recursive call
    s.map(          //   for each entry in s[],
    g = (           //   using a recursive callback function g taking:
      c,            //     c = current character
      i,            //     i = current position
      q             //     q = iteration counter, initially zero'ish
    ) =>            //
      !s[i] |       //     if s[i] is undefined
      q >> k ?      //     or we've done 2 ** k iterations:
        i           //       stop and return i
      :             //     else:
        g(          //       do a recursive call:
          c,        //         pass c unchanged
          [...s, c] //         append c to a copy of s[]
          .indexOf( //         and look in there for the position of
            c,      //         the next occurrence of c
            i + 1   //         starting the search at i + 1
          ),        //
          -~q       //         increment q
        )           //       end of recursive call
    )               //   end of map()
  ]                 //
:                   // else:
  []                //   stop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
ＩＥ⁵Ｅθ§⁺Φ⌕Ａθλ›νμＥφＬθ⊖Ｘ²ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBCsIwEER/JccE4kXw5KkoiqDQXwjb1S5sdtskrf59bOhcHryZgTEk0MC19omk2EvIxb7CZE/eNMzedOUhA/5sz0u2N@KCaYMMHXOr2XlzTxiaFm@ic/vz7c0T5VNGO7vmrggJI0rBwfb63dZHb8jtOdc6CS5RRRcuKUSCpBl0IsjEBLoqQxAFFdJMuR5W/gM) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Outputs each index on its own line with each set of indices double-spaced from each other. Explanation:

```
  ⁵                     Literal integer `5`
 Ｅ                      Map over implicit range
    θ                   Input string
   Ｅ                    Map over characters
        ⌕Ａ              Find all occurrences of
           λ            Current character in
          θ             Input string
       Φ                Filtered where
             ν          Occurrence index
            ›           Is greater than
              μ         Current index
      ⁺                 Concatenated with
                φ       Predefined variable `1000`
               Ｅ        Map over implicit range
                  θ     Input string
                 Ｌ      Length
     §                  Indexed by
                     ²  Literal integer `2`
                    Ｘ   Raised to power
                      ι Outer value
                   ⊖    Decremented
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you misread the problem statement

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh Sorry I'm always doing that. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 92 bytes

```python
lambda*s:clip(N:=len(s),0,x:=a(17*s,0,"s"))[2**c_[:5]+a(x)[:N]]
from numpy import*
a=argsort
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3Y3ISc5NSErWKrZJzMgs0_Kxsc1LzNIo1dQx0KqxsEzUMzbWKgWylYiVNzWgjLa3k-Ggr01jtRI0KzWgrv9hYrrSi_FyFvNLcgkqFzNyC_KISLa5E28Si9GIgE2pHV0FRZl6JRpqGllJiYjYEZicCDeRCSBRXpqSnlBSnZVaUlmWkpGcWZ6alVOaXZSWnF6MqLMzNL6oiDwANgrhowQIIDQA)

Expects the splatted input string and returns a 2D array of integers.

#### How?

Repeat the input to make sure at least 16 excess copies of every letter are available. Do an indirect sort, i.e. a sort we can take back by applying the inverse permutation. Apply the sort, shift by 1,2,4,8 or 16 and unsort. Clip to range.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
m@C.e+fgTkxbcz1mlzGz^2d5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9fBWS9VOy09JLsiKbnKMDenyr0qzijF9P//xMRsCMxOBAA)

#### Explanation

```
                            # implicitly assign z = input()
   .e              z        # enumerated map b, k over z, indices
          xbcz1             #   get all indices of b in z
      f                     #   filter this on lambda T
       gTk                  #     T >= k
     +         mlzG         #   pad with 26 copies of len(z)
  C                         # transpose
m                      5    # map d over [0-4]
 @                          #   the element at the index
                    ^2d     #   2 ^ d
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 90 bytes

```haskell
f s=[[([n|(n,x)<-z,x==c,i<=n]++l)!!(2^j)|(i,c)<-z]|let l=length s:l;z=zip[0..]s,j<-[0..4]]
```

It's got a perfectly natural typing, and uses 0-indexing as is normal for Haskell.

```haskell
f :: String -> [[Int]]
```

[try it online, with tests](https://play.haskell.org/saved/m28fqrOb)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave/MATLAB, 174 bytes

Modified from [@loopy walt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259318/110802)

Golfed version, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5BTsMwEEX3PYXVDWNhUB0hIRUhcYJcAFWVG9upW8c2Hie4LLh6cEoQYcvM7s/7T@ObJAY1jrp3TTLekUyeiYZBRBFb4@iKlMGSSd8frIJGWVt1Iv0S9OnK1IWxyrXpCDhHr5@M5F3J0ccEUYWph4wz/kgXiHFS5X0QMVVkN8N5vmvjhN1fieI5YC5/wkuwPf7pAd/W9I4zEvy7ilAxstk@0Pub2TJ1O@OgExnyhG0oIzWFhf2WF1Y5OUqDATSshTh/71msKV39xHiRrUyoTe6Ho2wNGi0vfjg1LS6xt87Hj/9N0Yxf)

```matlab
function x=f(varargin),s=double(cell2mat(varargin));N=numel(s);[~,x]=sort(repmat(s,1,17));[~,i]=sort(x);f_i=bsxfun(@plus,i(1:N)-1,(2.^(0:4)).');x=min(max(x-1,0),N)(f_i+1);end
```

Ungolfed version:

```matlab
function x = f(varargin)
    s = cell2mat(varargin);
    s = double(s);
    N = length(s);
    s17 = repmat(s,1,17);
    [~, x] = sort(s17);
    x=x-1;
    index_part1 = power(2, 0:4).';
    [~, index_part2 ]= sort(x);
    index_part2 = index_part2(1:N)-1;
    clipped = min(max(x, 0), N);
    sum_matrix = bsxfun(@plus, index_part2, index_part1);
    final_index = sum_matrix;
    x = clipped(final_index+1);
end

disp(f("aakakakakka"))
disp(f("sydgdtsfixuvhdgisifdyovjcgs"))
disp(f("qmorzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 92 bytes

```arturo
$[s][map 0..4'x[i:0map s'c['i+1(char? select.with:'j.n:2^x drop s i'm->c=m)?->j+i->size s]]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?GRPr6p)